# Comparing a string to a sequence of chars

Tags: python, arrays, string, char

I have the following string

```
"long"
```

And I have an array of `chars` that will contain the sequence `[..., [l],[o],[n],[g],...]` somewhere in it. Can someone help me find a way to compare the `string` to the array of `chars` and return a `True` or `False` without having to join the array into one `string`?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `[..., [l],[o],[n],[g],...]`? Do you mean `[..., 'l','o','n','g',...]`? Note that this is a list of **strings** each of which having only one character. Python does not have a primitive character type.

Comment: After writing an answer, I see that you cannot use `join()`. To solve this by hand, I suggest breaking it down into smaller pieces. Try to solve an example on a piece of paper. Think carefully about the steps you take to do it without a computer. Write out those steps **in words**. Then when you have a clear idea of those steps in your mind, try to translate those words into Python code.

Comment: Is there a reason why not to join the array into one string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't claim you should do it this way, but you certainly could.

```
z = "long"
a = [letter for letter in z]
b = ['l', ' ', 'x', 4, 'l', 'o', 'n', 'g', 5]
for i, j in enumerate(b):
    if a == b[i:i+len(a)]:
        print('"{}" found at index {}'.format(z,i))
```

Effectively we explode the string and then create slices of the list for comparison to the exploded string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
s = 'long'
lst = [['a'],['l'],['o'],['n'],['g'],['z']]

p = [[x] for x in s]
any([p==lst[i:i+len(p)] for i in range(0, len(lst)-len(p))])

Out[81]: True
```

Question in comment: "How to get the index of first match?"

```
[j for j, i in enumerate(range(0, len(lst)-len(p))) if p==lst[i:i+len(p)]][0]

Out[83]: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I studied the code for a bit and this seems to be a perfect solution. One more question, if I wanted to get the index of these characters from the list/array (or just the index of the first character at least), is there any built-in method for that?

Comment: @Hasan Updated my answer, if it was helpful, please consider upvoting and accepting it, to help future readers and it gives me a few points. Happy coding!